# Data is undefined in try catch block inside useEffect using async/await, but works when switching to Promises

Tags: reactjs, async-await, next.js, try-catch

So I have code that looks something like this:

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    if (someData) {
    try {
    console.log('inside try block', someData) // undefined
    const response = await get(apiUrl('urlInObject') + `${someData}`, {
      someData,
    })

    const { returnedData: someData, someOtherReturnedData } = response
    setDataInSessionStore({
      someData,
      someOtherReturnedData,
    })
    showNotification({
      type: 'success',
      message: `The operation was successful.`,
    })
    router.push('/pages/other-page')
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 400) {
      showNotification({ message: `${error.data}` })
    }
    if (error.code === 404) {
      showNotification({
        message: `'${someData}' is not valid. Please try again.`,
      })
      router.push('/pages/different-page')
    }
    console.error('ERROR: ', error)
  }
  }, [])
```

Source of setDataInSessionStore imported from store.js, using zustand with persist:

```
import create from 'zustand'
import { devtools, persist } from 'zustand/middleware'

// items in here don't expire on hard refresh
export const useSession = create(
  devtools(
    persist(
      (set, get) => ({
        dataInSessionStore: {},
        setDataInSessionStore: (dataInSessionStore) => set({ dataInSessionStore }),
          }),
          {
            name: 'my-session', // unique name
            getStorage: () => sessionStorage,
          }
        )
      )
    )
```

Inside the showNotification component:

```
import React from 'react' 

let ref

export function showNotification (notification) {
  ref && ref.setState({ ...ref.state, ...notification, open: true })
}

export class Notification extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { open: false, message: null, type: 'error', length: 3000 }
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    if (this.state.message) {
      this.timeout && clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      this.timeout = setTimeout(
        () => this.timeout && this.setState({ open: false }),
        this.state.length
      )
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.timeout && clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  }

  render () {
    const { open, message, type } = this.state
    if (!ref) ref = this
    if (!message) return null
    return (
      <div className={`notification-bar ${type} ${open ? 'bar-open' : 'bar-closed'}`}>
        <span className='text'>
          {message}
        </span>
        <div className='close-icon' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Notification
```

And here's the example of the code that works using Promises:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (someData) {
    setLoading(true)
      get(apiUrl('someUrl') + `${someData}`, {
        someData,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          const { data: someData, someOtherData } = response
          setDataInSessionStore({
            someData,
            someOtherData,
          })
          showNotification({
            type: 'success',
            message: `The operation was successful.`,
          })
          router.push('/pages/other-page')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.code === 400) {
            showNotification({ message: `${error.data}` })
          }
          if (error.code === 404) {
            showNotification({
              message: `'${someData}' is not valid. Please try again.`,
            })
            router.push('/pages/different-page')
          }
          console.error('ERROR: ', error)
        })
    }
  }, [])
```

I logged the data outside of the try-block and the data exists, but the data inside the try-block is undefined. If I switch the code to use Promises instead of async await + try-catch, the data exists. I am using NextJS and using zustand store with persist to set data to session storage.

Comment: This may be an over-simplified code example as nothing in it is asynchronous other than the `someFunction` declaration, so it's rather difficult to know or understand what your *real* code may be doing. If what you describe is true then in your code somewhere between the early return and the try/catch the `someData` value becomes undefined. It is it what is between these two points that is interesting.

Comment: @DrewReese you're right, I edited my post to add the rest of my code in the try/catch

Comment: Looks like `setDataInSessionStore` is enqueueing a state update but then a few lines later you imperatively navigate to a new route, which likely unmounts this component. Can you expand your code example to include what `setDataInSessionStore` is?

Comment: setDataInSessionStore sets my data in my session storage using zustand and persist middleware. I've updated my code example to include it

Answer (score 0):

You should append `someData` to the array of second argument of `useEffect` because `someData` is one of the local state and your side effect is depended on `someData`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-shirley-34eii?file=/pages/%5BsomeData%5D.js) is a CSB I've created.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const someFunction = async () => {
    if (!someData) return
    try {
      console.log(someData) // someData is undefined

      // make an API request with the data and do something
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('ERROR: ', error)
    }
  }

 someFunction()

}, [someData])
```

Comment: I'm not sure why `someData` is undefined in try-catch even though you are doing an early return, I tried your code in CSB and couldn't see it.

Comment: The `someData` constant equal to `router.query` can be conditionally undefined by definition. `router.query` is of type `ParsedUrlQuery` which resolves to types `string | string[] | undefined` when written as `const {someData}=router.query`. This is because `someData` is destructured, so it's equivalent to writing `router.query.someData`.

Comment: @AndrewRoss I know but if `someData` is undefined, it is early returned `if (!someData) return`, so it may not proceed to the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to query data within that component for a dynamic page or for a JSX.Element with props that ultimately ends up being rendered in a dynamic page (such as [slug].js)?

If the above case is true, then you just have to append whatever your dynamic page is called within the square brackets onto the end of `router.query`

For example, for a file `pages/services/[slug].tsx`, I call the following:

```
    const router = useRouter();
    const slug = router.query.slug as string;
```

you might be wondering why I assert `as string` after `router.query.slug`; the reason for doing so is because `router.query.slug` resolves to `string | string[] | undefined`. Since it isn't a catch-all route, I only want a single parsed string value for the slug.

That said, `router.query` itself is of type `ParsedUrlQuery` which has the following type definition:

```
interface ParsedUrlQuery extends NodeJS.Dict<string | string[]> {}
```

You might be wondering where the conditionally undefined value comes from, since it isn't evident in any of these definitions so far. The dictionary in `NodeJS.Dict` is where the root of the conditionally undefined resides:

```
interface Dict<T> {
    [key: string]: T | undefined;
}
```

Which is ultimately how you're getting `undefined` in your try block

To break it down for you, there is a function called `interpolateAs` in `node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/router/router.d.ts` that is defined as follows:

```
export declare function interpolateAs(route: string, asPathname: string, query: ParsedUrlQuery): {
    params: string[];
    result: string;
};
```

It is looking for the [*name*].js or [*name*].tsx for the `route`; this *name* must be appended to the parsed url query (router.query.*name*) for your data to be properly parsed.

Comment: It's for a page called something like pages/services/index.js, and I'm obtaining the query parameter appended to the end of the url

Comment: have you tried adding a `finally` block by chance? I know that useEffect can be weird.  Also, since the try catch block isn't callable, that could be the issue...

The first argument in useEffect should be some callback function; the second a watcher for the callback itself, invoking it when it's time. An IIFE wrapper could do the trick here (nesting try catch with `()` parentheses to make it callable).